# Injecting CSS based on config and flickering

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, stylesheet

Just wondering if anyone knows how to get around this issue. I add the external CSS links to header to AppComponent ngOnInit. It works ok however the page briefly flickers and displays the html before it adds the stylesheets. I have tried to hide the html until after the link injection but still does have the same behavior. Here is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, AfterViewInit, ViewEncapsulation, OnDestroy  }  from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ConfigurationService } from './services/configuration.service';
import { SessionService } from './services/session.service';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import './operators';
import { InjectCssService } from './services/injectcss.service';

/**
 * This class represents the main application component.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `
      <div [hidden]="isLoading" class="router-output">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {
  isLoading : boolean;
  configService: ConfigurationService;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document,
    private configurationService: ConfigurationService,
    private injectCssService: InjectCssService,
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private router: Router,
    private titleService: Title,
  ) {
    this.configService = configurationService;
    this.isLoading = configurationService.isLoading;
    sessionService.Initialize();

    titleService.setTitle(configurationService.config.title);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    Object.keys(this.configurationService.config.cssUrls).map(url => {
      let head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      let style = head.getElementsByTagName('link')[1];
      let link = this.injectCssService.createLink(this.configurationService.config.cssUrls[url]);
      console.log(link);
      head.appendChild(link);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: The phenomenon that you are experiencing is known as FOUC (flash of unstyled content). You will experience this whenever you dynamically are adding external styles to the page after the DOM has been loaded. How are they configured in your config? Are they just a static list or are they somehow dynamic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: I can think two ways to resolve this: 1. server-side rendering  or 2. data resolve guards and routing

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Thanks for that. it is dynamic list so the array could vary have N number of stylesheets.

Comment: @pixelbits I thought about server side rendering. Could elaborate on 2. Not quite sure I follow.

Comment: It doesn't look like the list is an observable based on your usage above. Is this list known at the time the code is compiled?

Comment: Yes the list is known at the time the code is compiled.

Comment: Are these stylesheets external to your project (e.g. on a CDN, etc.)? Or are they part of the source (e.g. from node_modules, etc.)?

Comment: If they are external, you can modify the `index.html` file that the CLI uses (as its template in the `.angular-cli.json` file - the `index` property gives the file name) and put them directly in there instead. If they are not, you could modify the `.angular-cli.json` file and add the files to the `styles` array.

Comment: These are CDN stylesheets. I think I'll go with modifying the index.html.

Answer (score -1):

Angular loads data asynchronously by retrieving data through a web service before rendering the page. There may be a noticable flicker as the page loads the stylesheets, calls the webservice, and renders the DOM.

To get around this, you can setup data resolve guards so the data is fully loaded before the route changes.  This allows the component to load and render the data without waiting; thereby significantly minimizing the flicker effect.

Here is an example route:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent, resolve: { data: MyDataResolver } 
}]
```

**MyDataResolver.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { MyDataService } from './mydata.service';

@Injectable()
export class MyDataResolver implements Resolve<MyData> {

  constructor(private myDataService: MyDataService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.myDataService.getData();
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    MyDataService,
    MyDataResolver
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**main.component.ts**

```
@Component()
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  mydata: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mydata= this.route.snapshot.data['data'];
  }
}
```

More info about data resolvers: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html